# How did an "arm" become a "mile"?

Tags: popular-refrains, origin-unknown

The common saying ***["give an inch and they'll take a mile"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/give-an-inch-and-they-ll-take-a-mile)*** 
 means:

> - Make a small concession and they'll take advantage of you.
>     For example, *I told her she could borrow the car for one day and she's been gone a week—give an inch!*

It is a very old saying which originally had a differen phrasing:

> - This expression, in slightly different form, was already a proverb in John Heywood's 1546 collection, *“Give him an inch and he'll take an **[ell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ell),***” and is so well known it is often shortened (as in the example). ***The use of mile dates from about 1900.*** (Dictionary.com)

The same expression is common also in other languages where "the arm", unlike in English, is still part of the saying:

> Donnez-leur en long comme le doigt, ils en prendront long comme le bras (French)
>
> Dale un dedo y se toma hasta el codo (Spanish)
>
> Dai una mano e si prendono un braccio (Italian)

Questions:

- What is the origin of the saying? Was it an original English one or was is "imported" from a foreign language?
- Why was "ell" changed to "mile" (a very different measure) around the beginning of the 20th century?

***Edit:***

1) - the assumption that *ell* has fallen completely out of use does not appear to be supported by available reference: ( [Ngran](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20an%20ell%2C%20take%20a%20mile%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20an%20ell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20mile%3B%2Cc0) "take a mile vs take an ell". )

2) - idiomatic expressions don't typically rely on their literal meaning, so the need to change from *ell to another common measure* doesn't appear to be the only possible reason for the change.

Comment: The second question is easy. What's an ell? Why use a measure no-one's heard of (let alone knows how long it is)?

Comment: The foreign sayings are *"give him a finger, and he'll take an arm"* (French), *"give him a finger and he'll take a forearm"* (Spanish), and *"give him a hand and he'll take an arm"* (Italian). Nothing about inches.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - it could be, but why not a "yard" which would have been more comparable to an arm in length.

Comment: @Josh61: I don't see any reason why, when an English idiom changes an archaic unit to a current one, it has to go back to the original foreign origin of the saying (if that's where it actually came from) and make the new unit of measurement compatible with the etymology.

Comment: @PeterShor - are you saying that you don't see any reason why  I should ask this question?

Comment: @Josh61: I think your first question (what is the origin?) is an excellent question. I don't see why you expect the *inch-finger* and *ell-forearm* correspondence to have been preserved after the saying changed.

Comment: An inch is in many languages a _thumb_, which could explain the finger / inch variations. An ell was the distance from the elbow to the tip of the fingers (hence elbow?), or the length of the (fore)arm. Sayings that exist in many different languages tend to have a common origin, often biblical. I cannot find a biblical origin for this one though...

Comment: @PeterShor - actually what made me think about a possible question was the arm/mile issue.

Comment: @oerkelens - yes the inch refers to a thumb ...

Comment: I'd expect someone not knowing what an 'ell' is to mishear as 'mile' rather than 'yard'

Comment: *In England, the ell was usually 45 in (1.143 m), or a yard and a quarter. [It was mainly used in the tailoring business but is now obsolete](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ell).* Wikipedia

Comment: Conflate your original saying with "A miss is as good as a mile".

Comment: It took you only ten days to find an obsolete term. OK. But today we have metres, and kilometres, it's seems pretty reasonable to me that speakers would substitute ell with a better-known unit of measurement. "One fell swoop" is not a single word, I suppose you might argue why don't native speakers say "One fierce swoop"? It's a line from Shakespeare, and although we may not understand what "fell" actually means in that phrase, many will have probably studied Macbeth at school, and have heard it being used in plays, movies and novels. We still understand the meaning behind the idiom.

Comment: I've deleted a few comments of mine.

Comment: @PeterShor I can add to your list the Dutch: "Geeft men hem den vinger, dan neemt hij de geheele hand" (old style), translated literally "give him the finger, then takes he the whole hand".

Answer (score 7):

As [Peter Shor commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325637/how-did-an-arm-become-a-mile-2?noredirect=1#comment741333_325637), the foreign expressions are all related explicitly to parts of the body:

> "give him a finger, and he'll take an arm" (French),
>   "give him a finger and he'll take a forearm" (Spanish), and
>   "give him a hand and he'll take an arm" (Italian).

While "inch" may be about a thumb's-width*, it's a unit of length, so "ell" needs to be replaced with a unit of length, and "mile" has a suitable element of hyperbole. The continental expressions are parts of the body, so the hyperbole is body-related too, rather than explicitly distance-related. That is, the comparison must be within a single class.

"Yard" would certainly have a been a contender to replace an obsolete comparison, but since there is a more hyperbolic word in the same class, *mile,* why not use that?

---

*Edward II defined the inch in terms of three [barley-corns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barleycorn_(unit)) laid end-to-end, so even the thumb isn't really relevant here.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know where the phrase came from, but the reason for the change from "ell" to "mile" is obvious: the word *ell* had fallen completely out of use.

In fact, the last time I saw it used was in the early 1970's, describing this exact expression in an story from the 17th century: the Earl of Donegal was attempting to get control of an "inch", a Gaelic word for a freshwater island, and a political opponent wisecracked, "Give him an inch and he'll take an ell."  After the Earl won the struggle and gained title to the inch, he rubbed it in by changing the spelling of his title to "Earl of Donegall" -- taking an *l*.

The story is probably apocryphal, but the county and the peerage are spelled differently for some reason.

Comment: [Brad Howard](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/316452/brad-howard) comments that the *ell* version occurs "in Verne’s ‘Journey to the Center of the Earth,’ in chapter 20, where the Professor, Henry & Hans are trying to get to the subterranean river through a wall of granite. The worry is that as they are pick-axing away at the wall to get to the much-needed water, that the river, “having gained an inch would take an ell,” and come rushing catastrophically through the new opening. This quote dates from mid- to late-1800’s."